# How do I prevent my program from terminating?

Tags: python

I created a leap year calculator but the only problem is that once it prints out its statement it terminates.

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))
leap_year_check = False
already_a_leap_year = False
if year / 4 == int(year / 4):
    if year / 100 != int(year / 100):
        already_a_leap_year = True
    elif year / 100 == int(year / 100):
        leap_year_check = True

if year / 400 == int(year / 400) and leap_year_check and already_a_leap_year == False:
    print("Leap year")
elif already_a_leap_year == True:
    print('Leap year')
else:
    print('Not leap year')
```

Comment: Clearly, you need a loop.  Add `while True:` to the beginning and indent the rest.

Comment: By the way, `if year % 4 == 0` is smarter than what you have, which requires multiple integer/float conversions.

Comment: `leap_year = (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)`

Comment: What's bad about terminating? You haven't told us what you want it to do instead...

Answer (score 0):

you want to keep repeating the same operation :

So the solution is to embed everything in **while True** loop

```
while True:
    year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))
    leap_year_check = False
    already_a_leap_year = False
    if year / 4 == int(year / 4):
        if year / 100 != int(year / 100):
            already_a_leap_year = True
        elif year / 100 == int(year / 100):
            leap_year_check = True

    if year / 400 == int(year / 400) and leap_year_check and already_a_leap_year == False:
        print("Leap year")
    elif already_a_leap_year == True:
        print('Leap year')
    else:
        print('Not leap year')
```

Comment: God bless you, thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution. Looks like you want the program continue after it check the input. I add more the option to continue or exit program after check process done.

```py
terminate_program = False
exit_program_map = {"Y": True, "N": False}

while not terminate_program:
    year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))
    leap_year_check = False
    already_a_leap_year = False
    if year / 4 == int(year / 4):
        if year / 100 != int(year / 100):
            already_a_leap_year = True
        elif year / 100 == int(year / 100):
            leap_year_check = True

    if year / 400 == int(year / 400) and leap_year_check and already_a_leap_year == False:
        print("Leap year")
    elif already_a_leap_year == True:
        print('Leap year')
    else:
        print('Not leap year')


    is_exit_program = str(input("Do you want to continue program? [Y/N] ")).upper()
    if is_exit_program in exit_program_map.keys():
        terminate_program = exit_program_map[is_exit_program]
    else:
        print("Not valid option. Shutdown program")
        terminate_program = True

    if terminate_program is True:
        print("Shutdown program")
        break
```

Example

```
Which year do you want to check? 2022
Not leap year
Do you want to continue program? [Y/N] N
Which year do you want to check? 2018
Not leap year
Do you want to continue program? [Y/N] n
Which year do you want to check? 2015
Not leap year
Do you want to continue program? [Y/N] Y
Shutdown program
```